# Discord.py rewrite : "Mute" command not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am attempting to mute a user.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await user.mute(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'{user} has been muted')
```

I receive the following error:

```
Member object has no attribute "mute"
```

How can I mute a user?

Comment: What code do you have so far? What have you already looked up?

Comment: The bot idea might not be very friendly to other users but is very doable, but first you need to give us information about your preferred language of code and your research, this is a site in which people help others that need help with a real problem, not a site in which you order yourself a programmer. Begin writing the code yourself and if you are experiencing issues come back here and ask freely. Just don't forget to add documentation to everything.

Comment: Rather than rewrite your old question with this one, why wouldn't you just make a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def mute(ctx, user : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await user.edit(mute = True, reason = reason)
    await ctx.send(f'{user} has been muted')
```